# substr_replace() doesn't work as expected in WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysql, substring

substr_replace() doens't work as expected because i'm in while loop

**PHP**

```
$c= "2013-01-01 12:00:00";
$d= "2013-01-02 12:00:00";
$date_3 = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime("$c"));
$date_4 = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime("$d"));

$results = array($date_1);
$i = $date_3;
while ($i <= $date_4) {//here start the while look
$i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime($i));
array_push($results, $i);
$k= $i . "\n";
$chunks = str_split($k, 19);
$nexstring = join('\')', $chunks);//2013-01-01 12:00:00') 2013-01-02 12:00:00') 2013-01-03 12:00:00')
$cane = implode(
', (\'',
str_split($nexstring, 21)//2013-01-01 12:00:00'), (' 2013-01-02 12:00:00'), (' 
);
echo substr_replace($cane, '(\'', 0, 0);//sub_string doesn't give my expected output
$i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($i)));
}//end while
```

where

```
 $nexstring = 2013-01-01 12:00:00'), (' 2013-01-02 12:00:00'), ('
```

and

```
 $cane=('2013-01-01 12:00:00'), (' ('2013-01-02 12:00:00'), ('//1 more parenthesis added to the second date.
```

I'm expecting **$cane to be**

```
('2013-01-01 12:00:00'), (' 2013-01-02 12:00:00'), ('// my expected output
```

Probably as I'm in the "while" it adds one more '(\'' of those

Original string

```
2013-01-01 12:00:00 2013-01-02 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're coming from `$date_1` or `$date_4` - not clear - and want to have 2 days added as two other dates, formated in to a combined string as `('2013-01-01 12:00:00'), ('2013-01-02 12:00:00'), ('2013-01-03 12:00:00')` - same time, just one and two days later. What about this:

```
$date = new DateTime($date_1);
$out = "('" . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "')";
for ( $n = 1; $n < 3; $n ++ )
{
   $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
   $out .= ", ('" . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "')";
}
echo $out;
```

Comment: very nice of you to look into this long code, but this not what I was looking for. I have a problem with substr_replace while in loop.

Comment: `substr_replace($cane, '(\'', 0, 0);` is wrong syntax: It won't replace anything by given length of 0 (fourth parameter). It will insert at offset (0), same as `$cane = '(\'' . $cane`. Thus, works as designed, and all the stuff is not needed for the problem.